# Send/Receive byte[] via TCP Socket

Tags: java, android

1. I would like to send/receive sqlite database files (*.db) in byte[] over TCP socket connection?
2. Is there a similar method in Java/Android for Socket.Poll() C#?

I'm new in Java / Android

Comment: 1. OK. 2. Really? "I don't know what X do in C#, but I want to know its equivalent in Java"? ---- In other words, please be more specific, and show what you have tried, if you put some effort in your question, people will put effort in their answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Socket](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) class.

There is no `Poll` method, however there are other methods that can be used to check the socket status.
For example, you can use `Socket.isOutputShutdown()` to check if the output stream is available (Whether it has been shutdown or not), and you can use `Socket.getInputStream().available()` to get the number of bytes available to read *now*.