# Android-Send/Receive byte[] via TCP Socket

Tags: java, android

I would like to send/receive sqlite database files (*.db) in byte[] over TCP socket connection?

Comment: Yes I guess you would like that... Is this a rhetorical question?

Comment: Please don't ignore the comments on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505398/send-receive-byte-via-tcp-socket). Vote to close. again.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[9182];
int nBytesRead = 0;
while ((nBytesRead = fis.read(buffer) != -1)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, nBytesRead);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
fis.close();
```

Comment: Google knows this as well: Try to google "java socket file transfer"